# How to get ID and change background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to change a background color of a div when the user click on the button. How I have 5 divs, each ID will be different.

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $valorPremio = 0;
?>

@foreach($premios as $premio)
    <div class="pure-g" data-id="{{$valorPremio++}}" id="premioCaixa{{$valorPremio}}">
        <div class="pure-u-17-24">
            <span class="tituloPremio">{{$premio->titulo}}</span>
            <span class="dataPremio">{{substr($premio->data,8,2);}}{{'/'.substr($premio->data,5,2)}}{{'/'.substr($premio->data,0,4)}}</span>
            <p class="subtituloPremio">{{$premio->subtitulo}}</p>
            <div class="textoPremio">
                {{$premio->olho}}
            </div>
            <div class="textoPremioEscondido hide">
                {{$premio->texto}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-6-24">
            <img src="assets/images/premios/{{$premio->imagem}}" alt="{{$premio->titulo}}" class="pure-img"/>
            <div class="leiaMais" href="">VER MAIS +</div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

#### Javascript

```
$(function() {
     $('.leiaMais').click(function(){
        var textoPremioEscondido = $(this).parent().parent().find('.textoPremioEscondido');

        if(!textoPremioEscondido.hasClass('show')) {            
            // Exibe o conteúdo do texto oculto
            textoPremioEscondido.slideDown(function() {
                textoPremioEscondido.addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
                textoPremioEscondido.parent().parent().find('.pure-u-6-24').css('background-color', '#004351');
                textoPremioEscondido.parent().css('background-color', '#004351');
                textoPremioEscondido.parent().find('.textoPremio').css("color","#fff");
                textoPremioEscondido.parent().find('.textoPremioEscondido').css("color","#fff");
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.leiaMais').html("VER MENOS -");


            });
        }
        else {
            // Remove qualquer texto que esteja sendo mostrado
            $('.pure-u-17-24').find('.show').slideUp(function() {
                $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
                $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#9BAAAF');
                $(this).parent().find('.textoPremio').css("color","#004351");
                $(this).parent().find('.textoPremioEscondido').css("color","#004351");
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.pure-u-6-24').css('background-color', '#9BAAAF');  
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.leiaMais').html("VER MENOS +");
            });
        }

    });
});
```

## Explaining this Javascript

For now, this javascript only shows a text and change bg colour of 2 divs. The class ".pure-u-17-24" is inside of div that has the ID "premioCaixa+NumberofCounter".

## What I've tried

I put this 2 variables immediately after "var textoPremioEscondido..."; dataIdDiv obtain a number, and I've use it for get the ID of div.

```
var dataIdDiv = $(this).parent().parent().data("id");
var idDiv = $(this).parent().parent()[dataIdDiv].id;
```

After this I've saved the file and test the slideUp and slideDown. Only the first DIV could execute the javascript, executing the 2 effects, different of the others, how did nothing.

The idea is use the code(below) inside the slideUp and slideDown function to change DIV background-color.

```
idDiv.css('background-color', '#004351');
```

Comment: Adding an index to parent() doesn't make sense to me since elements can only have one parent. 
var idDiv = $(this).parent().parent()[dataIdDiv].id;

Comment: DO you want to change the color of what div? `.pure-g`?

Comment: What do you exactly wanna do? I don't understand that all stuff above

Comment: Note that the foreach is creating an "infinite" amount of divs, since he is pulling the information from the database. For each div I own a "Read More" button, I want to change the color of the div shake when this button is inside it.

Comment: There's no div `shake` in posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regular JS without JQuery.

```
document.getElementById('the_id').style.backgroundColor="AA0000";
document.getElementById('the_second_id').style.backgroundColor="AA0000";
//etc.
```

Or make it easier by adding a class to each div

```
document.getElementsByClassName('the_class').style.backgroundColor="AA0000";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things difficult for yourself. You should just get the division using

```
    var e = document.getElementById('whichever div');
    e.style.background = '#aa0000';
    // plus any other processing
```

It would be quicker (less DOM lookups) and requires less code than all that stuff above.

I you wnat to make some sort of reusable code, then try a function like

```
        function backgroundChange(myDiv, newBackgroundColor){
            var e = document.getElementById(myDiv, newBackgroundColor);
            e.style.background = '#aa0000';

        }
```

Comment: Each div are different information of a table. Using this, all divs how content the class "pure-g" will be changed

Comment: What about jquery? :)

Comment: `$("target").css("background", "black")`

Answer (score 0):

```
textoPremioEscondido.parent().parent().css('background-color', '#004351');
```